# TSQL XML Query Question

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2008, nodes

Is this possible in TSQL?

I am feeding this structure in via an xml param.  And I need to set it into a temp table.

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = '<Events>
            <Event id="8">
                <Responses>
                    <Response id="59">
                        <Loe>
                            <Id>89</Id>
                        </Loe>
                    </Response>
                    <Response id="60">
                        <Loe>
                            <Id>89</Id>
                            <Id>90</Id>
                            <Id>88</Id>
                            <Id>87</Id>
                        </Loe>
                    </Response>
                </Responses>
            </Event>
        </Events>';
```

Trying to display it like:

```
EventId    ResponseId     LoeId
8          59             89
8          60             89
8          60             90
8          60             88
8          60             87
```

I tried to use this query, but it throws an error.

```
SELECT
  [data].value('../../@id','varchar(100)') AS EventId,
  [data].value('@id','varchar(100)') AS ResponseId,
  [data].value('Loe/Id','varchar(100)') AS LoeId
FROM @xml.nodes('/Events/Event/Responses/Response') as Test([data])
```

But if I remove the LoeId it works and I get this:

```
EventId    ResponseId
8          59             
8          60
```

What I am doing wrong?  How do I address the Loe->Id in the query?

I am using MSSQL 2008.  Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do it:

```
SELECT
    event.value('@id', 'int') AS Event,
    response.value('@id','int') AS Response,
    id.value('.','int') AS LoeId
FROM
    @xml.nodes('Events/Event') AS t1(event) cross apply
    t1.event.nodes('Responses/Response') AS t2(response) cross apply
    t2.response.nodes('Loe/Id') AS t3(id)
ORDER BY Event, Response, LoeId
```

Comment: your earlier example data contained several Event nodes, so that handles it as well

Comment: @K Ivanov  Thank  you very much.  I was so close , yet so far away!  Awesome answer and greatly appreciate.  It really cleared things up for me.